# Transcribing subdivision coordniate geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, cogo

I spend a lot of time at my current job looking at subdivision plats and am curious about how they are actually created and am seeking a better understanding of them from a mapping perspective. I have QGIS 3.32

My first question is what coordinate system is used for subdivision plats, or what is standard? I am sure it changes depending on the area of the world you are in, but given that none of the subdivision plats I look at ever specify a coordinate system I am assuming there is some standard. Now whether that is UTM,state plane, or something else entirely, I have no idea.

I see that everything is in degrees rather than units of measurement like feet or meters, does this mean they are using WGS84?

As I mentioned, I understand these maps are created with a starting point and all measurements are relational to each other. How is the starting point denoted, if it is at all?

I have attached a screenshot of one boundary, how do I go about mapping this digitally? Would I identify the correct coordinate system, input the coordinates, and then measure 261.78' from that point?

[image: Example Boundary]

Comment: Can you provide the whole map?

Answer (score 3):

This is really a comment but it is too long for that box.  Many if not most of the old survey/plan maps I had to deal with were created without any reference to a coordinate system. Your snippet looks familiar. The surveyor (or just an ordinary person) would get their numbers from instruments on the ground going point to point. Later but still old plans referenced a coordinate system and that was usually stated on the map notes or plan box.  If you are lucky they referred to a government survey marker for the start point.  More recent maps might even have a GPS coordinate.  But for the others you have to make things fit as best as you can using features. The plan map would typically show a north arrow or magnetic north arrow but sometimes didn't indicate which, or the declination if magnetic.  You can try using the map year to calculate a declination from a NOAA site like https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml#igrfwmm. The old maps usually indicated in some fashion what units the bearing distances were in like feet in your map snippet, or in a scalebar, but sometimes not.    A lot of maps like the snippet showed distances in decimal chains or chains and rods.  You may have to try different units to see which make sense.

I would make a shape from the bearings and distances. (For years I continued to use ancient Arcview 3x to set the distance units and approximate the expected location, the NWF/DEM extension to create the shape from the bearings and distances and the XTools extension to export that to a shapefile, as that put off choosing a coordinate system when none was there/known.)  The CRS would be chosen or changed in the project I added the shape to.  QGIS has tools like the azimuth and distance plugin or Advanced Digitizing panel which you could use to create shapes amongst others but you need to pick a first try coordinate system.

If there were enough well distributed features to use as control points I would also try to georeference the map as imaged/scanned.  That would make it easy to try different coordinate systems and the result would help in the moving and rotating of the shape. Then I would add the shape to an ArcMap or QGIS project with a commonly used projected coordinate system, and move and rotate (start with the calculated declination if there is one) the shape to see if I could fit it in with other plans, any available imagery or vector data (like roads) and topographical features.  Contours might help if available but they often were crude. I might try different coordinate systems but the difference of state plane and UTM was way below the accuracy of the effort.  Don't use geographic systems. Don't expect perfection.